# Which of two methods of using python within erlang should I use?

Tags: python, erlang

I have a project where I use erlang to aggregate RSS, and I use python to process the RSS feeds.

Method 1:

Use an erlang port, using erlport.org, to call python.
   I'm not sure how to design the python code to be asyncrhonous using erlport.

Method 2:

Use erlang to call on a RESTful interface with Tornado that does the processing (asynchro downloading of urls -- asynchro procssing)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked Erlang<->Python before but erlport.org seems promising. I would try that first before getting into greasiness with REST and what not. I.e. I didn't provide and answer but a recommendation :)

Comment: I have the erlport method working. I'm likely to also try Tornado and compare the two methods. I'm just interested in seeing what methods people have found effective.  Method 2 seems better, as the app would then be available to other applications.